# Exercise on Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, analysis

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for every $a<b$, the integral $\int_a^b fdf$ exists and is $0$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

The attempt at a solution:

I would like to pick an arbitrary $c \in \mathbb R$ and a fixed number (call it $a$) and conclude that $f(c)=f(a)$ for every $c \in \mathbb R$.

I know that if I fixed $a$, then for $c : a<c \space$, $\space 0=\int_a^c fdf=f^2(c)-f^2(a)-\int_a^cfdf=f^2(c)-f^2(a)$, so $|f(a)|=|f(c)|$. If $c<a$, analogously I would conclude that $|f(c)|=|f(a)|$, but this is not sufficient to prove the function is constant, from here all I would conclude is that the function takes two values: $f(a)$ or $-f(a)$.

Comment: The way it's written you'll get $\int_{a}^{c} f\; df = \frac{c^2-a^2}{2}=0$. This implies that $|c|=|a|\; \forall a,c \in \mathbb{R}$ which is nonsense. Surely you mean $\int_{a}^{c} f(x)\; dx$?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but I don't see why $\int_a^c fdf=\frac{c^2-a^2}{2}$. All I did was apply integration by parts: $\int_a^b f(x)dg(x)=f(a)g(a)-f(b)g(b)-\int_a^b g(x)df(x)$.

Comment: There is one mistake: actually $\int_a^b f(x)dg(x)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^bg(x)df(x)$. But either way, one concludes $|f(c)|=|f(a)|$ for every $c \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: To answer your question: I read $f\; df$ as the same as $x\; dx$. Frankly, in the time I've taken and tutored calculus, I have never seen $f\; df$ written; I recommend writing $f\cdot f'\; dx$; this is much clearer especially since your bounds of integration are in the $x$-variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that integration by parts gives
$$
\int_a^c f\,dg = fg(c) - fg(a) - \int_a^c g\, df.
$$
(You made two mistakes: the order of the boundary terms was wrong, and you forgot the leftover integral.) So when $g=f$, this becomes
$$
2\int_a^c f\,df = f^2(c)-f^2(a).
$$
In this particular case, you can still recover the conclusion $|f(c)|=|f(a)|$, but I thought it was worth pointing out the mistakes for other situations.

Anyway, if $f(a)=0$ then you've shown that $f(c)=0$ for all $c$. If $f(a)\ne0$, then you know that $f(c)=\pm f(a)$ for all $c$. But since $f$ is continuous, it's impossible for it to be $f(a)$ at one point and $-f(a)$ at another: if that happened, then it would take the value $0$ somewhere in between, by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Since $\int_a^c fdf=0$, I didn't bother to write it, but thanks for the remark and the other correction.

Comment: I've thought of another way to prove that $f$ can't take two values, but I want to check if it is correct: Suppose $f$ takes the values $f(a)$ and $-f(a)$, if we consider $f$ restricted to its image, then the image of $f$ is discrete. Take $x. y \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=f(a)$, $f(y)=-f(a)$, since $\{f(a),-f(a)\}$ is open and $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}\{f(a),-f(a)\}=\{x,y\}$ must be an open set in $\mathbb R$, which is clearly false.

Comment: Yours is much shorter and simpler, but I like to know more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: Your alternate proof isn't correct. $f^{-1}(\{f(a),-f(a)\}$ contains $\{x,y\}$ but doesn't have to be limited to $\{x,y\}$. In fact $f^{-1}(\{f(a),-f(a)\}$ is the whole real line. Also, $\{f(a),-f(a)\}$ isn't an open set to begin with. However: take open intervals $U,V$ such that $f(a)$ is in $U$ but not $V$, and $-f(a)$ is in $V$ but not $U$. Then $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are disjoint open sets whose union is $\mathbb R$. But $\mathbb R$ is connected. So the only possibility is that one of $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ is empty and the other is all of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$  est à  valeurs dans $\{f(a), -f(a)\}$ comme l'image d'un intervalle par une application continue est intervalle $f$ prend toujours la valeur $f(a)$ ou toujours la valeur $-f(a)$. le cas $f(a)=0$ est un cas particulier

Autrement dit $\mathbb R$ est connexe donc $f(\mathbb R)$ est aussi connexe c'est à dire est un intervalle; donc il est réduit en un point.

Comment: This is an English-language website.  Can you please post your answer in English?